structure multiple figures and texts in the same file
I am using Latex to write a research paper and I am trying to figure out, how to structure more than a figure and text in the same page. I use the commands \begin{figure}[h] and \end{figure}[h]. Between this commands I just use the \includegraphics command twice to include the pictures in the page, I also add a table using the \begin{tabular} and \end{tabular} commands. I do this three times, but if I create a subsection between the figures it just moves the figures at the end of the file. I would like to have for every subsection a figure.

Welcome to TeX SE. Could you post a minimum compilable example to show what you tried? I'll be easier to help you.

The answer of Frank Mittelbach on How to influencethe position of float environments answers this question:

"Here" really just means "here if it fits"
... and often it doesn't fit. This is somewhat surprising for many people, but the way the algorithm has been designed the h specifier is not an unconditional command. If an unconditional command is needed, extension packages such the float package offer H as an alternative specifier that really means "here" (and starts a new page first if necessary).

\usepackage{float}

\begin{figure][H]
  \includegraphics{example-image}
\end{figure}

